# Pass array of objects in a view and loop in each object

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am passing an array of objects to a view:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> IndexJson()
{
    // Define cols
    Object[] tableColumns = {
        new { data= "id", name= "Id" },
        new { data= "code", name= "Code" },
        new { data= "name", name= "Name" },
        new { data= "colorCode", name= "ColorCode" },
        new { name= "Actions" },
    };
    ViewData["TableColumns"] = tableColumns;
    return View("IndexJson");
}
```

and then In .cshtml:

```
@{
    var cols = ViewData["TableColumns"];
}
<div id="data_table">
    <table class="table" id="listview-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                @foreach (var item in cols)
                {
                    <th>item.name</th>             
                }
```

"cols" is underlined and gives error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error
> (active)  CS1579  foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type
> 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public instance or
> extension definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try  to stop the compiler from issuing an error by casting to dynamic, like this:

```
 @foreach (var item in (dynamic)cols)
                {
                    <th>@item.name</th>
                }
```

result:
[image]